# Adapt Boost Thread / Process for non supported platform

Tags: c++, boost, real-time, boost-thread, boost-interprocess

**Background**

[this](http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process/boost_process/platforms_and_compilers.html)  documentation says that it is possible to **adapt the library to new (unsupported) operation system**. Because the OS (a real time OS) I would like to support is **close to Win32**, I would expect little code changes. I have no experience with Boost Thread and Boost Interprocess .

**Questions**

- Would you recommend to use Boost's Thread and Boost's Interprocess, if the
  plattform is not supported?
- What are the benefits and drawbacks?
- Which alternatives would you consider?

Comment: Boost development is not for the faint of heart, but you can probably exploit some of the existing test-cases.

Comment: It' RTX form Interval Zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this depend on your needs. Using a portable library has the obvious advantages. Stabilizing a new platform could take some time.

I would suggest you to create tickets for each one of the features that doesn't work for the specific platform and work closely with the Boost authors.